# Failed to set the 'buffer' property on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': Failed to convert value to 'AudioBuffer'

Tags: javascript, audio, socket.io, web-audio-api, mediastream

I am trying to use socket.io and mediastream to send audio in realtime between clients. I was able to record, send that data to the server and then to a different client. But when I try to convert the arraybuffers to audiobuffers and then connect them to an audio output device, i get the error message

```
Failed to set the 'buffer' property on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': Failed to convert value to 'AudioBuffer'.
```

I dont understand why this is happening. Here is some of my code.

client side

```js
const socket = io();
const audioCtx = new AudioContext()
const audioC = new AudioContext()

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      console.log('getUserMedia supported.')

      navigator.getUserMedia(
        { audio: true },
        stream => {
          const source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
          const processor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1)

          source.connect(processor)
          processor.connect(audioCtx.destination)

          processor.onaudioprocess = e => {
            socket.emit('Voice', e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0))
          }

          socket.on('Voice', msg => {
            const source = audioC.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = msg;
            source.connect(audioC.destination);
            source.start()
          })
          audioCtx.resume()
        },
        err => console.error(err)
      )
    }
```

server side

```js
//Server shit
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const { stringify } = require('querystring');
const { compileFunction } = require('vm');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
const PORT = 3000 || process.env.PORT;
server.listen(PORT,  console.log('Server is running on port 3000'))

//variables
var clients = [{}]
var rooms = [{}]

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.on('Voice', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg)
        socket.emit('Voice', msg)
    })

})
```

at this point in the code..

```js
socket.on('Voice', msg => {
            const source = audioC.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = msg;
            source.connect(audioC.destination);
            source.start()
          })
```

when I log the msg, it gives me an arrayBuffer, and then i use the process above to convert the arrayBuffer to an audioBuffer yet it just gives me the same error message. Ive been banging my head against a wall for days now to try and figure this out so if anyone has a solution I would extremely appriciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that you're sending is the channelData which is a `Float32Array`.

```
socket.emit('Voice', e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0))
```

I'm not that familiar with socket.io but I assume the data arrives on the other end as a `Float32Array`, too. In that case you will have to build an `AudioBuffer` with that data before you can use it with an `AudioBufferSourceNode`.

```
const audioBuffer = new AudioBuffer({
    length: msg.length,
    sampleRate: sampleRateOfTheAudioContextOfTheSender
});

audioBuffer.copyToChannel(msg, 0, 0);
```

That `audioBuffer` can then be used with the `AudioBufferSourceNode`.

```
source.buffer = audioBuffer;
```

Comment: The data arrives as a arrayBuffer, when I console log the data it logs "arrayBuffer(8192)"

Comment: I was able to just create a Float32array and use what you gave me in this example and It worked, but the quality is bad and choppy. I saw someone who had the exact problem as this and someone answered that with changing the baud rate and decreasing the sound quality that it will fix this issue, the problem is that I dont know how to do that

Comment: Update: all is well and your solution worked perfectly, all i had to do was change is to a float32Array and then take out a line of code that i used for debugging but never took out. Once I took it out, there was zero choppiness and it all worked smoothly. Thank you so much for the help!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that.